# Excel-If range criteria met, sum all range that have been divided by 5 then round up

Tags: excel-formula

Need your help on below.

[image: screenshot]

I would like to sum all the action count (the action count need to be divided 5 first then round up before summing it all up ) if criteria(Action type) is "A".

I tried to use the formula

```
=sumif(B2:B6,"A",roundup((A2:A6/5),0))
```

I tried to press ctrl+shift+enter to make it as a array formula but I prompt error. And the result I want is 4 from the above formula.And if the criteria change become "B" the result will be 5.

I tried to find a way in Google but unable to find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an old style (pre-SUMIF) style of array formula.

```
=SUM(IF(B2:B6="A", CEILING(A2:A6/5, 1)))
```

Finsih with CSE.